# A problem with rewriting summations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I want to rewrite the following:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\Omega}\sum_{k,l \neq -k', k''}V_{l-k}u_{k}v_{k}v_{l}u_{l} - \frac{1}{\Omega}\sum_{k,l }V_{l-k}u_{k}v_{k}v_{l}u_{l}
       \end{align}
Using the following relations:
\begin{align}
V_{l - l} = 0 \:\:\: \forall l 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
2u_{k}v_{k} = \frac{\Delta_{k}}{\sqrt{\zeta_{k}^2 + \Delta_{k}^2}} 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\Delta_{k} = -\frac{1}{2\Omega}\sum_{l}V_{l-k}\frac{\Delta_{l}}{\sqrt{\zeta_{l}^2 + \Delta_{l}^2}}
\end{align}
This should become equal to
\begin{align}
\frac{\Delta_{-k'}^2}{\sqrt{\zeta_{-k'}^2 + \Delta_{-k'}^2}} + \frac{\Delta_{k''}^2}{\sqrt{\zeta_{k''}^2 + \Delta_{k''}^2}}
\end{align}
I tried doing this but I'm not sure if I should "complete" the first summation before using the third relations. If I don't do this I get the result except there is a $\frac{1}{2}$ infront. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It seems to me that you can write the first relation as $V_0=0$ as well instead of $V_{l - l} = 0, \forall l$.

Comment: Yes that is true I just wanted to make it extra clear.